# Guard statement in Swift has error if using return

Tags: swift

I have this code

```
 guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else{

            print("No URL")
            return

        }
```

the `return` statement produces an error

> Non-void function should return a value

Omitting the `return` gives me error below

> 'guard' body may not fall through, consider using 'return' or 'break' to exit the scope

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: You need to return a value appropriate to the function's return type and the fact that you have an error. Show your function if you need more specifics in an answer.

Comment: FYI - In Swift use `URL`, not `NSURL`.

Comment: but what's the return of a guard statement? It's basically an if statement so how can that have a return value? I'm just trying to exit the body of the guard statement. URL is giving me errors.

Comment: You have to return any value in Non-void function.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs Show your function in your question if you want better help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is saying that your `guard` statement is within a `func()` that has an expected return value of some `type`

For example in the `greet()` function a `String` is returned… so the `guard` statement must return a `String` value.  The `type` of the value you have to return from your `guard` statement will depend on the function that contains it.

```
func greet(person: String, day: String) -> String {
    guard person != "Homer" else {
        return "Sorry, no Homer's allowed"
    }

    return "Hello \(person), have a great \(day)"
}

greet(person: "Homer", day: "Monday")

greet(person: "Douglas", day: "Thursday")
```

If the `String` "Sorry, no Homer's allowed" isn't returned in the example `greet()` function you will see the same problem:

[image: broken guard statement]

A `guard` statement simply protects against an unusable state for the function it's enclosed in. So the `return` statement of a `guard` is just a form of early `return` for the function, as such, it must return the same type as the functions definition.

In the `greet()` function above the definition specifies that a `String` is returned (`-> String`) , so the `return` inside the `guard`'s else block **must also** return a `String`.

Comment: I put a return statement in the function, and it worked. I did a guard statement again, and now the error is back even with a return for the function.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs see my edit… basically the guard return and the function return are both required, and both must match the function signature